# Overriden compareTo() not recognised in priority queue

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue, compareto

Ive implemented compareTo() in a Disk class and even though it works fine when i use it in main, it gives me the following error when i try to compile the priority queue which is using the same method:

MaxPQ.java:113: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
         if ((Disk)heap[i].compareTo((Disk)heap[max]) >= 0)

Any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
public class Disk implements Comparable <Disk>{

    public static int count = 0;
    public int id;
    //public Node folders;
    public int freeSpace;

    public Disk(){
        count++;
        id = count;
    }

    public int getFreeSpace(){
        return freeSpace;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Disk d){
         return Integer.compare(this.getFreeSpace(), d.getFreeSpace());
    }


}
```

And:

```
public class MaxPQ<Disk> {


    private Disk[] heap; // the heap to store data in
    private int size; // current size of the queue
    //private Comparator comparator; // the comparator to use between the objects

    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 4; // default capacity
    private static final int AUTOGROW_SIZE = 4; // default auto grow


    //public MaxPQ(Comparator comparator) {
    public MaxPQ() {
        this.heap = (Disk[])new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1];
        this.size = 0;
        //this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    private void sink(int i) {
        // determine left, right child
        int left = 2 * i;
        int right = left + 1;

        // if 2*i > size, node i is a leaf return
        if (left > size)
            return;

        // while haven't reached the leafs
        while (left <= size) {
            // Determine the largest child of node i
            int max = left;
            if (right <= size) {
                if (heap[left].compareTo(heap[right]) < 0)
                    max = right;
            }

            // If the heap condition holds, stop. Else swap and go on.
            // child smaller than parent
            if ((Disk)heap[i].compareTo((Disk)heap[max]) >= 0)
                return;
            else {
                swap(i, max);
                i = max;
                left = i * 2;
                right = left + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.heap = new Disk[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1];` gives me "error: generic array creation" when i compile so thats why i casted there. As for the `(Disk)heap[x]` casts, i left them in the code by accident while trying to debug it

Comment: You are missing `)` after `((Disk)heap[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Disk` as a generic type parameter, then trying to use it like a class.

It doesn't look like `MapPQ` should be a generic class. It uses `Disk` specifically. So I'd:

1. Change the declaration so it's not generic;
2. Use `new Disk[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1]` to create `heap`;
3. and remove all of those casts

If you did want `Disk` to be generic (convention is to use a single letter, not a word; I'll use `T` which is overwhelmingly the letter used for the first generic type argument), when instantiating `MapPQ` you'd have to have the caller pass in the `Class` instance it should use for the array. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) for how you do that, but roughly:

```
public MapPQ(Class<T> cls) {
    ths.heap = (T[])Array.newInstance(cls, DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1);
}
```

(Or declare `heap` as `Object[]` and keep all your casts, but it's error-prone.)

Comment: Removing `<Disk>` from the maxPQ declaration and then just using `new Disk[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1]` for the heap made it work. Cheers for the answer!